# How to suspend a task from within a kernel module (Linux)?

Tags: c, linux, kernel

I have a Linux kernel module that runs every 10 seconds and scans whether there are any resource-hogging processes. I then need to suspend them for a minute (i.e. six loops through the code) and let them run again afterwards. I have already written the code to check for the condition, and have all the appropriate task_struct pointers.

The question is, how do I suspend a task, given its task_struct pointer? And later on, how do I resume that task?

Comment: What you're describing is probably better done in userspace than in the kernel.

Comment: This is a homework question, which is why it's rather artificial.
The homework policy does not permit asking for help from anybody except me. In case any genuine enquirer happens upon this post, I should note that my students have an old and slightly patched kernel, which exposes one or two kernel functions that are hidden in recent kernels.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could suspend the process by sending it `STOP` signal, then resume it by sending it a `CONT` signal; perhaps via `kill_pid(task_pid(task_struct), SIGSTOP, 1)` and `kill_pid(task_pid(task_struct), SIGCONT, 1)` for example.

That approach is not perfect. For example, another process can keep such a process running by sending it `CONT` signals, unless you also block `CONT` signals during the time-out period.

Answer (score 2):

Send `SIGSTOP` from inside the kernel with [send_sig](http://lxr.linux.no/linux+v3.6.3/kernel/signal.c#L1489) if you have the task_struct. Then send `SIGCONT` to resume it. Processes cannot ignore `SIGSTOP` (or `SIGKILL`).

Or try [send_signal](http://lxr.linux.no/linux+v3.6.3/kernel/signal.c#L1148) and use `SEND_SIG_FORCED` for the siginfo.

Comment: I'll try that, thanks. Do I have to acquire a lock for the task_struct, or is send_sig SMP safe?

Comment: Looks like it locks it for you, at least in the most recent kernel http://lxr.linux.no/linux+v3.6.3/kernel/signal.c#L1212

Comment: I managed to stop the processes using `send_sig(SIGSTOP, p, 0);`, where p is the pointer to the `task_struct`, but it seems the processes do not respond to `send_sig(SIGSTOP, p, 0);`. Is there something in the invocation that I am doing wrong?

Comment: Sorry do you mean they don't respond to `SIGCONT`?

Comment: I send them SIGCONT, as above, but they remain stopped. Aren't they supposed to continue running after receiving the signal?

Edit: oh yeah, that was a typo. They don't respond to SIGCONT.

Comment: I tried `send_sig_info(SIGCONT, SEND_SIG_FORCED, stopped_procs[i].task);`, still no response. The process remains stopped.

Comment: If you stop from the kernel, can you restart from the user space?

Comment: Well, after all the attempts, I realised that this is not a good solution because the user of the stopped process can just call `kill -SIGCONT [pid]` and resume it, which is not what I need. Suspending the  process has to be invisible to the user. And it all needs to happen from within the module (requirements... bah).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, you can remove the task from the run queue, save it somewhere and put it back later.

Another way could be reducing its priority. Although this doesn't prevent it from running, it would prevent it monopolizing the cpu.

Comment: Could you please give me a tip as to how I can accomplish the first thing: removing the task from the run queue. I scoured sched.h for the functionality, but I can't seem to find it. Thanks :)

Comment: I wouldn't mess with the run queue. Instead, add a per-process flag you can access from the scheduler, and don't schedule a process with that flag set.

Comment: @bladerunner1992 In `kernel/sched/core.c` look for `deactivate_task()` and `activate_task()`. I haven't done this myself, but I would experiment with these functions or copies, if they aren't exported. Maybe setting the `state` to `TASK_STOPPED` works as well.

Comment: @NominalAnimal Why not? Modifying the scheduler, to ignore some task states, is IMO more complex than de-/activating a task. Although `TASK_STOPPED` might be already sufficient for this.

Comment: @OlafDietsche I was afraid it would interfere with the corner cases, like OOM. Now that I checked, it doesn't: dequeuing a task from the run queue does not affect the task list (and the only reason you need to keep a handle to the task is so you can requeue it later; the kernel will keep correct track of it). I haven't needed anything like this myself, and using the task list seemed much more fragile than the relatively straightforward scheduler modification. Consider me corrected ;)

Comment: I think it's still relevant, I'd like to keep Firefox open at a page but the page's Javascript is taking 100% CPU.  sigsuspend sounds perfect.  I just tried kill -s 19 then later kill -s 18 but it wouldn't continue.  Maybe it did, I just had to reload the page.